# How to use auth()->attempt() in Laravel with credentials splitted over 2 tables?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, credentials, laravel-authentication

I want to authenticate a user based on 3 pieces of information. For example an id, a verification code, and a password. The problem is that the id and password are in a table saying "user" and the verification code is in a second table called "vcodes". I would like to authenticate this user with the auth() function in Laravel in addition with the jwt-auth package. However, there is always the error message that the verification code was not found. that also makes sense, since it is not in the same table. Is there already a solution for this or can someone help me?

I have already tried passing the verification code as an attribute to the model that is to be authenticated. Unfortunately, that didn't work because the auth() function searches directly on the table.

Comment: Auth::user() brings user model, on the `vcodes` table, has the right reference to the `user_id`? did you make a relation in the User model to this table?

Comment: Yes, the relation is set. But doesn't Auth::user() return the already authenticated user?

Comment: return the model of the user, that is the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

A crude way to do it would be to use verification _code as a foreign key in a column on your user table, However this is messy and assuming you just want to use email verification you can just use

```
class User extends Authenticable 
implements MustVerifyEmail {

use Notifiable;

}
```

You can just follow the docs Https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/verification

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).